# Display Charts in SharePoint 2010 WITHOUT using Excel Services and Chart Web Parts

Tags: web-part, chart-web-part

I use Sharepoint 2010 and the Chart Web Part is disabled.
Is there another way of displaying charts ? (by using a HTML or Sliverlight Web part for example ?)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Check out this question for more examples on how you can do that: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29093/how-to-programmatically-create-a-chart-in-sharepoint/

Comment: Not that stack would ever support the use of third party tools, but have you talked to your company about third party tools? You're going to spend your entire existence re-inventing the wheel here. The licenses aren't too expensive depending on the tool. A quick google search will do you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [google api](https://developers.google.com/chart/?hl=en&csw=1) for creating charts online.
Or [MsCharts](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Unfortunately Google Services are blocked in my company

Comment: Added an extra link

Comment: Along the same lines, in the past I've successfully used Raphael and JQuery to create charts where almost everything was blocked / locked down in a bank. I loaded the JS files in to a doc library and was able to achieve quite respectible charting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with 
http://www.jqplot.com/

some sample example 
http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/

Comment: I've used JQPlot in the past; the hardest part about it is creating all the SOAP requests and the underlying data structure to dynamically scale the charts. Works ok though!