# Display Excel chart on page in a web part

Tags: 2013, chart-web-part, excel-web-access-webpart, sharepoint-server

I have a pivot table chart I would like to display on a Sharepoint page.  Fast forward to [2mins 58sec in this Kalstrom video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10yLQNklKOU) where he inserts an Excel chart in to a web page.  I'd like to do the same.

I'm using SP 2013 On Premises.

I've found a few good posts where a web part called `Excel Web Access` is used; this web part is part of a group called `Business Data`.  I don't have this web part.

I've read that a feature called [SharePoint Server Enterprise Site features](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_online_support_blog/2015/12/10/cannot-add-an-excel-web-access-web-part-in-sharepoint-online/) but I don't see this feature at all.  I'm using SP2013 On Premises, could it be because this feature is only in Enterprise?  As you see here:

[image: features]

I'm also open to finding other ways to display the chart.  In the past I have saved the Excel tab (chart), I thought I'd mention that as an option to others in the same situation as me.

[image: html page]

Any other suggestions please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I could achieve what I needed another way, so I didn't need to mess with Features in the end.

I found I could save individual Excel tabs as .htm/.html web pages.  I saved these to a Wiki Page Library.

[image: pic]

For each graph I created a new wiki page and used the **Page Viewer** web part to embed the .htm/.html file I created from Excel.  Make sure you save them all in the same place (i.e. the same Wiki Page Library).

[image]

Then I made a new page as a Graphs Menu, just a simple page with links to the wiki pages, just to make it easier for the users to find the graph they are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are running Sharepoint Foundation not Enterprise so you don't have that features available.

Have a look at this thread it may give some ideas about alternatives.

[Display Charts in SharePoint 2010 WITHOUT using Excel Services and Chart Web Parts](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77112/display-charts-in-sharepoint-2010-without-using-excel-services-and-chart-web-par)